# AIX malloc is returning unaligned memory?

Tags: c, alignment, malloc, aix

We are using AIX's `malloc`. According to IBM's help pages on [malloc, free, realloc, calloc, mallopt, mallinfo, mallinfo_heap, alloca, valloc, or posix_memalign Subroutine](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/malloc.htm):

> The malloc subroutine returns a pointer to a block of memory of at least the number of bytes specified by the Size parameter. The block is aligned so that it can be used for any type of data. Undefined results occur if the space assigned by the malloc subroutine is overrun.

After we copy data into the buffer and ship it off to vector unit we get incorrect results because the buffer is ***not*** 16-byte aligned. The page does not discuss `vector` data types or special needs. The `vector` data types are a standard type on PowerPC cpus.

My first question is, what does IBM mean when they say *"The block is aligned so that it can be used for any type of data"*? Does it include vector data types?

My second question is, does IBM make a function available for 16-byte alignment like Intel's `_mm_malloc`? If so, what is it?

Comment: I do not remember "vector" as a C data type.

Comment: Thanks @ulix. The pages do not state the memory is aligned for C data types; it says any data type. On a PowerPC that seems like it should include the vector data types, which have been present for about 15 or 20 years. Maybe I am splitting too many hairs...

Comment: When you say "After we copy data into the buffer and ship it off to vector unit we get incorrect results because the buffer is not 16-byte aligned." is it possible you are mis-alligning it during your "copying and shipping"...??  Have you printed out the address that malloc returns and checked to see if it is 16 bit alligned..??  I recall having issues storing pthread structures (mutex et. al.) inside of a structure and  not maintaining allignment... so I do know that alignment CAN be an issue.

Comment: You might read [THIS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/vector_prog.htm) ...   specifically the paragraph entitled: "Vector memory allocation and alignment"

Comment: Thanks @Tony. I think you should answer because that is the missing information.

Comment: Are you observing the virtual memory address? If so, what makes you think the physical memory address isn't suitably aligned?

Comment: In fact... How are you observing this? I'd like to see your code, and the output. It's possible that you may be misinterpreting something.

Comment: @Sebivor - I have a wrapper function called `AlignedAllocate`. The function calls `malloc` because it returns a pointer with alignment suitable for any data type on AIX. It also has an assert that fires whenever the return address in to 16-byte aligned. The assert is placed right before the `return ptr;`. We were observing alignment as small as 2 and 4 in some cases. You can see the function here: [`AlignedAllocate`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/58f6b7695b5227faa04eee17b71094868746431e/misc.cpp#L281).

Comment: Do you realise that `malloc` typically returns what's called a *virtual address*, which isn't required to compare in any meaningful way to a *physical address* and therefore carries no meaning regarding *alignment*?

Comment: Thus this: `size_t adjustment = 16-((size_t)p%16);` <--- `p` does not carry alignment info, despite what you think. `(size_t)p%16` is a lie.

Comment: In spite of that, the standard does not use terms like "unaligned"; it uses terms like "suitably aligned" and "undefined behaviour". More specifically, it requires that `malloc`s return value be *suitably aligned* to store any kind of data... which does not necessarily mean it needs to be *a multiple of sixteen*; it means *any kind of data could reside at that address, and the machine would not complain*. Technically speaking, *everything* has alignment, and thus the term *unaligned* is a misnomer.